# Spring MVC - Display Blob images from Database

Tags: database, image, jsp, blob, apache-commons

Firstly, I am new to Spring MVC and I am really sorry if this seems like a duplicated question however I am struggling to find a break down guide/tutorial on how to display images on a JSP page after receiving them as blobs from the database. Most of the responses I've read just give you small snippets which confuse me more.

I have a MySQL DB which has a table full of images stored as blobs. I have a Service which retrieves the blob images from the database and populates an arrays of **CommonsMultipartFile**. I also have a Controller which passes the array to the JSP page where a loop iterates over each image which I'm trying to display.

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/my/images" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAllImages(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model) {

    final List<CommonsMultipartFile> images = new ArrayList<CommonsMultipartFile>();

    myService.getAllImages(images);
    model.addAttribute("myImages", images );

    return getUrl(request);

}
```

**JSP**

```
<c:forEach items="${myImages}" var="image">
    <img src="${image}">        
</c:forEach>
```

This is as far as I got. The images are not displaying. Please can someone help?

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best is to save those binary-files to harddisk (using pk as filename) and directly serve them to the browser.

You can write a Servlet too but its quite hard to write asynchron Servlets.